# How to find a specific comman string from multiple text files?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, grep

I have 10 different text files which contain the 700 image paths. I want that common ones in which the starting letter is "BarackObama" is retrieved i.e. Barack Obama which are common in all should be retrieved.

I tried the following set of commands but not getting the desired result:

```
grep --include=\*.{txt} -rnw '/home/ashutosh/Downloads/New_IIIT-CFW/' -e "Barack"
grep -Fwf results1.txt results2.txt results3.txt results4.txt results5.txt results6.txt results7.txt results8.txt results9.txt results10.txt
```

Please suggest any better alternative !!

Comment: Did understand correctly: you want the image paths which have "BarackObama" in them? Also, please post example data and expected output so that we don't have to guess what you want.

Comment: **NOT enough clear**

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, it will search for the string in the dir where you files are located.

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

Along with these, `--exclude, --include, --exclude-dir or --include-dir` flags could be used for efficient searching:

This will only search through those files which have .c or .h extensions:

```
grep --include=\*.{c,h} -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

**Or another way is to use xargs to speed up.**

```
find /path/to/dir -type f | xargs grep -l "stringtosearch"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of below commands. Output will show you list of files with their paths.

- > find /path -type f -exec grep -ilr 'search' {} \;
- > find /path -type f | xargs  grep -ilr 'search'